# React: Unable to access the parent component's function which is passed as prop to child component

Tags: reactjs

I have a TodoList component which is a child of the App component. I wish to change the state of the App component's todos list. I am attempting to pass a toggleComplete function from the TodoList component to the Todo component so at onClick event it would fire and work its way up to the App component so I could update the state.

I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleComplete' of undefined" in the TodoList.js

~/src/component/Todo.js

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class Todo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li className={this.props.todo.done ? 'completed' : 'view'}>
        <div className="view">
          <input onClick={this.props.toggleComplete(this.props.id)} className="toggle" type="checkbox" checked={this.props.todo.done} />
          <label>{this.props.id}: {this.props.todo.title}</label>
          <button className="destroy"></button>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

~/src/component/TodoList.js

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import Todo from './Todo'

export default class TodoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  toggleComplete(todoID){
    console.log('hit toggleComplete TodoList');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="main">
        <ul className="todo-list">
          {this.props.todos.map(function(todo, index){
            return <Todo todo={todo} toggleComplete={this.toggleComplete} id={index + 1} key={index+1}/>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

~/src/App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './component/Header'
import TodoList from './component/TodoList'
import TodoFooter from './component/TodoFooter'
import Footer from './component/Footer'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [
        {title: 'Taste JavaScript', done: true},
        {title: 'Buy Unicorn', done: false},
        {title: 'eat all day', done: false},
        {title: 'sleep all night', done: true}
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <section className="todoapp">
          <Header />
          <TodoList todos={this.state.todos} />
          <TodoFooter />
        </section>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to occur before the function makes it to your child component, as the error is coming from your parent component.  Your [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does not have access to the correct this, so it is treated as undefined -- try this instead:

```
{this.props.todos.map(function(todo, index){
  return <Todo todo={todo} toggleComplete={this.toggleComplete} id={index + 1} key={index+1}/>;
}, this)} // use the optional "this" argument to the map function
```

And here's a fiddle to play with showing a simple example of parents rendering their many children with the same reference to the parent's scope: https://jsfiddle.net/v5wd6Lrg/1/

Comment: Combination the map's 'this' param with binding the prop to 'this' got it work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The above answer can also be done using arrow function without binding

```
{this.props.todos.map((todo, index) => {
  return <Todo todo={todo} toggleComplete={this.toggleComplete} id={index + 1} key={index+1}/>;
});
```