# React call component's method from nested function in render method

Tags: javascript, react-native, reactjs

I would like to call the method updateCurrentThread onCLick, however I'm getting following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateCurrentThread' of undefined

```
updateCurrentThread: function(thread) {
  this.setState({
  currentThread: thread
 }).bind(this);
},


render: function () {
  var threads = this.state.data.map(function (thread) {
    var boundClick = this.updateCurrentThread.bind(this, i);
    let time = getThreadDate(thread.timestamp);
    return (
      <div className="row thread" key={thread.threadID}>
        <ThreadParticipants onClick={boundClick} key={i} className="small-2 small-centered columns" ids={thread.participantIDs}/>
      </div>
  );
})
```

Comment: this is referring to the function scope of the function that is the first parameter to `map`. Use `thread => { }` instead of `function(){}`

Comment: Looking into it... :)

Comment: Here's my entire react file: http://pastebin.com/Qs1uGiRk

Comment: I just answered a similar question relating to this references inside the map closure; this answer should assist you http://stackoverflow.com/a/35534177/4206756

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `this` inside your function is scoped to the function, not the component.  If you are able to use ES6 arrow functions, which are lexically scoped, then your current approach will work.  Before arrow functions, people would store the component `this` in a variable (e.g. `var self = this`) and then `self.updateCurrentThread`.